# I need the citation off in the list of tables when using longtblr

Tags: table-of-contents, citing, longtblr

I have this table:

```
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Gram Positive Bacteria.\cite{Bacterial_Classification}},
label = {Tab:Gram Positive Bacteria} ]{cells   = {font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
                      colspec = {@{} X[c] *{3}{X[0.8,c]} *{2}{X[1.5,c]} @{}},
                      colsep  = {7pt},
                      cell{11}{1} = {c=6}{},
                      row{1}  = {c, font=\bfseries},
                      rowhead = 1}
    \toprule

Name    &   Morphology  & O\textsubscript{2} Requirements
        &   Commensal   &   Reservoirs / Sites of colonization, Transmission
        &   Types of Infections \\
    \midrule
Staphylococci & Cocci in grape-like clusters & facultative anaerobe & Yes & Skin, nares / endogenous, direct contact, aerosol & Soft tissue, bone, joint, endocarditis, food poisoning \\
Streptococci & Cocci in pairs, chains & facultative anaerobe & Some species & Oropharynx, skin / endogenous, direct contact, aerosol & Skin, pharyngitis, endocarditis, toxic shock \\
Pneumonococci & Diplococci, lancet shaped & facultative anaerobe & Yes / No & Oropharynx, sinus / aerosol & Pneumonia, otitis, sinusitis, meningitis \\
Enterococci & Cocci in pairs, chains & facultative anaerobe & Yes & GI tract / endogenous, direct contact & UTI, GI, catheter-related infections \\
Bacilli & Rods, spore-forming & aerobic & Yes / No & Soil, air, water, animals / aerosol, contact & Anthrax, food poisoning, catheter-related infections \\
Clostridia & Rods, spore formers & anaerobic & Some Species & GI tract, soil / Breach of skin, endogenous, ingestion & Tetanus, diarrhea, gas gangrene, botulism \\
Corynebacterium & Rods, nonspore forming & facultative anaerobe & Some species & Skin & Catheter-related infections, diphtheria \\
Listeria & Rods, nonspore formers & facultative anaerobe & No & Animals, food products / Ingestion & Meningitis \\
Actinomyces & Irregular, filamentous, form sulfur granules & anaerobic & Yes & GI tract / endogenous & Skin, soft tissue \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
```

In the list of tables it appears as `Gram Postive Bacteria [1]`

How can I have a different caption for the table in the list of tables (in this example, I just do not need the citation there) and a different caption at the place the table is (I need the citation here).

For example, like this: `\caption[Gram Negative Bacteria.]{Gram Negative Bacteria.\cite{Bacterial_Classification}}` when using `\caption` command in a normal table.

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You all keep telling me that and you are totally right! I will read what a MWE exactly is and try to provide everything from now on.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the entry for the list of tables using the `entry=...` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Gram Positive Bacteria.\cite{Bacterial_Classification}},
entry={short version for lot},
label = {Tab:Gram Positive Bacteria} ]{cells   = {font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
                      colspec = {@{} X[c] *{3}{X[0.8,c]} *{2}{X[1.5,c]} @{}},
                      colsep  = {7pt},
                      cell{11}{1} = {c=6}{},
                      row{1}  = {c, font=\bfseries},
                      rowhead = 1}
    \toprule

Name    &   Morphology  & O\textsubscript{2} Requirements
        &   Commensal   &   Reservoirs / Sites of colonization, Transmission
        &   Types of Infections \\
    \midrule
Staphylococci & Cocci in grape-like clusters & facultative anaerobe & Yes & Skin, nares / endogenous, direct contact, aerosol & Soft tissue, bone, joint, endocarditis, food poisoning \\
Streptococci & Cocci in pairs, chains & facultative anaerobe & Some species & Oropharynx, skin / endogenous, direct contact, aerosol & Skin, pharyngitis, endocarditis, toxic shock \\
Pneumonococci & Diplococci, lancet shaped & facultative anaerobe & Yes / No & Oropharynx, sinus / aerosol & Pneumonia, otitis, sinusitis, meningitis \\
Enterococci & Cocci in pairs, chains & facultative anaerobe & Yes & GI tract / endogenous, direct contact & UTI, GI, catheter-related infections \\
Bacilli & Rods, spore-forming & aerobic & Yes / No & Soil, air, water, animals / aerosol, contact & Anthrax, food poisoning, catheter-related infections \\
Clostridia & Rods, spore formers & anaerobic & Some Species & GI tract, soil / Breach of skin, endogenous, ingestion & Tetanus, diarrhea, gas gangrene, botulism \\
Corynebacterium & Rods, nonspore forming & facultative anaerobe & Some species & Skin & Catheter-related infections, diphtheria \\
Listeria & Rods, nonspore formers & facultative anaerobe & No & Animals, food products / Ingestion & Meningitis \\
Actinomyces & Irregular, filamentous, form sulfur granules & anaerobic & Yes & GI tract / endogenous & Skin, soft tissue \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}


\listoftables

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, it was that simple, a command away. As always... Thanks a lot, I appreciate it!

Comment: @DGuys You're welcome!